# is there any way in perforce to check the diffs between the diffs of two files?

Tags: compare, diff, perforce, review

I regularly need to check if the changes of a changelist are the same as the changes of a reference changelist, I would like to know if there is any command or script to facilitate this

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem — if you’re really trying to answer the question of “was this change merged cleanly?” there are much easier ways to do this by reporting on the metadata rather than the actual content!  If you have identical changes that aren’t the result of merges, you have some other problem entirely that would almost certainly be easier to solve if you did use merging.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea that comes to my mind is to write a script that runs the p4 diff command (or p4 diff2, if you are comparing two different changelists on the server) for the two different changelists you want to compare and puts each of them in a separate text file. Then run p4merge and pass the files in as arguments.

```
p4 diff first_path/...@345 > diff1.txt
p4 diff second_path/...@347 > diff2.txt
p4merge diff1.txt diff2.txt
```

Hopefully that at least gets you started on some ideas!